# How to make a model damage a player in Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to know how to make a model damage a player. I tried this script, but it does not work. How can I fix it?

```
local Debounce = false
script.Parent.Touched:FindFirstChild(function(hit)
   if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and Debounce == false then
      Debounce = true
      hit.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(10)
      wait(0)
      Debounce = false
      end
   end)
```

Comment: Heyo YT_Xaos, when you say that the script doesn't work. What do you mean? Is it throwing errors in the Output window? Are players simply not taking damage? What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: Nope, it just does not damage the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script.Parent.Touched` is a signal, and you connect to it using the function `Connect`, not `FindFirstChild`:

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's why it wasn't working. Thanks!